# jquery mobile navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have no clue why this isnt working. Because I got so many pages and dont want to add the same footer over and over again I made up this which actually works.

```
        $(document).delegate('[data-role="page"]', 'pagecreate', function() {
          $(this).children('[data-role="footer"]').append('<div data-role="navbar">
     <ul><li class="nav-active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
         <li class="nav-active"><a href="#service">Service</a></li>
         <li class="nav-active"><a href="#settings">EInstellungen</a></li>
     </ul></div>');
         });
```

Unfortunately this doesnt work:

```
$('.nav-active').live('click', function() {
   $(this).addClass("ui-btn-active ui-state-persist");
});
```

Sorry I never worked with 
jFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KjubE/N7eqh/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("yourFooter").trigger('create');
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery live is depreciated, you can use the on method instead.
Is the rest of your code working?
Is the Element in DOM when performing this request?

Please take a look at the api documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/trigger/
This has to be executed after attaching with on.
For me it works like this. Do you need a fiddle?

Comment: A fiddle would be awesome.

Comment: then please provide a fiddle of your code. this is probably more easy.

Comment: I dont know how to use jFiddle - posted a link though.